# pip installs python library under wrong version of python

Tags: python, cherrypy, linux-mint

On the  Linux Mint O.S. I used pip to install the CherryPy module.  However it installed it under `python2.7` in :

> /home/jacslim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy

rather than under `Python 3.6` which I found in `/usr/bin/python3.6`,
  I tried again in the `Pyton3.6` directory but the same thing happened.

Is there anyway I can direct `pip` to use the latest version of the Python interpreter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pip3 install to install for python 3

Answer (score 0):

pip is usually in the same bin directory as your python, so make sure you just specify the correct bin housing your pip installation.

I use anaconda and my Python 2.7 is installed in:

```
/anaconda2/bin/
```

To get pip installs specific to that Python, I therefore use:

```
/anaconda2/bin/pip [name_of_thing_to_install]
```